# Highlight cells or rows with different colors by value

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I have a spreadsheet with thousands of rows of data.  I have created an index column and would like to highlight the cell or row (preferably) based on value.

I tried a color scale but that just made a gradient and did not work for what I was aiming for.

**This is what I'm looking to do**

[image: This is what I'm looking to do]

I need to avoid VBA code or Macros.
Excel version: O365

Comment: Thousands of rows will mean houndreds of colors. No matter the method (most likely 1 rule for each color) you'll end up with shades anyway. Is a coloring by even/odd acceptable?

Comment: @EvilBlueMonkey I think that should be okay.  It's really to help differentiate the changes in data to ensure I do not look at something that doesn't belong

Answer (score 0):

I 'm not sure if you can avoid macros.

Let's suppose you have 2 columns (A & B) and you want to color your rows based on the value of column A, which can be one of: **a,b,c,d,e,f,g** Something like this:

[image]

A simple solution is the following:

1. Create a Macro (Alt+F8)
2. Type a name for the Macro in Macro name, i.e. Format_rows
3. Select "Create"
4. Paste the following code between "Sub Format_rows()" and "End Sub"

   ```
    i = 1
    j = Sheet1.Cells(1, 1)

    While Not IsEmpty(j)

    cur_range = "A" & i & ":B" & i

    Select Case j

    Case "a" ' Color for value "a"
        col_code = 0.1

    Case "b" ' Color for value "b"
        col_code = 0.2

    Case "c" ' Color for value "c"
        col_code = 0.3

    Case "d" ' Color for value "d"
        col_code = 0.4

    Case "e" ' Color for value "e"
        col_code = 0.5

    Case "f" ' Color for value "f"
        col_code = 0.6

    Case "g" ' Color for value "g"
        col_code = 0.7

    End Select

    Range(cur_range).Select
         With Selection.Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent1
        .TintAndShade = col_code
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With

    i = i + 1
    j = Sheet1.Cells(i, 1)

    Wend
   ```

5. Modify Case "a", Case "b" etc. according to the values you wish to use to categorize your rows and remove or add more cases if necessary.
6. Save your excel file as ".xlsm".
7. Activate your main excel window and run the Macro (Alt+F8)>Run.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use a simple colour scale as conditional formatting, like in this screenshot?

[image]

Comment: It looks like the screenshot link is broken

Comment: He said he tried color scale and the shade isn't really effective. I think he is looking for marked differences between each group of values.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new sheet and paste this in cell A1:

| Data to be formatted | Formatting rule |
| --- | --- |
| a | =IF(A1="",FALSE,IFERROR(ISEVEN(SUM((OFFSET($A1:$A$2,-1,0)<>OFFSET($A2:$A$3,-1,0))*1)),FALSE)) |
| b |  |
| b |  |
| c |  |
| c |  |
| c |  |
| d |  |
| e |  |
| e |  |

On the column A you have a fake sample of your data. In cell B2 the rule that you will use to conditionally format the range. Now:

1. copy the formula in cell B2
2. select a cell in the first row
3. create a new name and paste the formula as reference
4. select range A:A
5. apply a conditiona formatting based on the name just created

### Formula analysis

An IF function checks if there is any data in the given cell. We don't want to color an empty cell (like at the end of the list), so if there is no content it returns FALSE.

*=IF(A1="",FALSE, **Step2**)*

An IFERROR function force the formula to return FALSE if the next step returns an error.

=IF(A1="",FALSE, *IFERROR(**Step3**,FALSE)* )

An ISEVEN function will check if the "index" of the range is even or odd.

=IF(A1="",FALSE,IFERROR( *ISEVEN(**Step4**)* ,FALSE))

A SUM function will count how many changes in values have taken place in the list this far.

=IF(A1="",FALSE,IFERROR(ISEVEN( *SUM(**Step5**)* ),FALSE))

We multiply our next step by 1 so any true or false result will be translated into 1s and 0s (so we can sum the trues).

=IF(A1="",FALSE,IFERROR(ISEVEN(SUM( *(**Step6**)*1* )),FALSE))

We compare two ranges of the same size offset one from the other by one row. This way we will track any change in the values. Each range have a fixed "starting row" and a dynamic "end row". This way they will cover the list from the start to the point the formula is displaced. We will also offset both ranges by 1 row in order to align the result to the actual list.

=IF(A1="",FALSE,IFERROR(ISEVEN(SUM(( *OFFSET($A1:$A$2,-1,0)<>OFFSET($A2:$A$3,-1,0)* )*1)),FALSE))